# Have there been any documented mini-moons since 2006 RH120?

Tags: asteroid, near-earth-object, asteroid-redirect-mission

The [conference call](http://spirit.as.utexas.edu/~fiso/telecon/Bottke_1-15-14/) with Bill Bottke (MP3 plus other documents) about "minimoons" presents an alternative to Asteroid Redirect first got me interested in orbital mechanics. The idea is that there are enough small asteroids that approach the earth-moon barycenter (EMB) that it seems likely there are frequent temporary captures of small asteroids into chaotic 3-body orbits in EMB system, that last for a few months to a few years.

Here is an example of one theoretical orbit [from here](http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/info/press-releases/minimoons/) or [here](http://sservi.nasa.gov/articles/simulations-show-mini-moons-orbiting-earth/):

[image]

One can read more in [Granvik, Vaubaillon and Jedicke 2012](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103511004684) (*The population of natural Earth satellites* Icarus, 218 (1) March 2012, pp262-277) available without paywall in [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3781).

Only one "minimoon" [2006 RH120](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_RH120) was known [by 2012](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/abs/2009/09/aa10965-08/aa10965-08.html), but it seems there should be new ones regularly, according to Granvik et al. 2012.

*Have there been others that were detected and reported?*

[image]

Comment: One has just been discovered, but it looks like it's been here for at least 50 years, so far longer than the type of orbit you're referrring to. http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=6537

Comment: @Hobbes that is great to know about! They call **2016 HO3** a "quasi-moon" because it's in orbit around the sun in a 1:1 resonance with earth. [Watch here](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=6537). They go around together, sort-of like a Trojan asteroid would. I'll have to read more - this is really interesting, at about 2.2 million miles a moon of earth would have a period of about 1 year, although that's if there were no sun. This one stays around 9 million miles away, so it's really in orbit around the sun, but in resonance with the earth. Curiouser and curiouser!

Comment: @Hobbes here's a crazy video of the trajectory, it just does a big figure-8 in a patch of the Celestial Sphere, bisecting Virgo and Leo  [The Trajectory of the Strange Object 2016 HO3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mVfE_qmQAg).

Comment: Remember, that's just the view from Earth. Just like the planets and their weird retrograde loops.

Comment: @Hobbes yep. But this would be the *first ever* thing that moves around a lot during the year, and yet always stays in one area relative to the stars - for at least an entire human lifetime. There's nothing that I can think of that has ever done that before. If it was bright enough to be visible - and if it had come a few hundred years earlier - it would be really quite unique, and forced Newton and Galileo to think scratch their heads a bit. I'm sure Newton would have caught on to resonances earlier.

Comment: @Hobbes  http://arksky.org/images/2016_ho3_5000_day_orbit.png

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would expect mini-moons to be commonplace around Earth.  Because we have our big Moon, a body coming from interplanetary space effectively undergoes a three-body interaction when it encounters Earth.  Energy can be transferred from an incoming body to the Earth-Moon pair, allowing the small body to be captured, and perhaps vice versa allowing the small body to later escape.

Comment: related: [How would a small TCO (temporarily captured orbiter) or other natural Earth satellite most likely be detected?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18387/7982)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly the earliest documented mini-moon was the one associated with the [1913 Great Meteor Procession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1913_Great_Meteor_Procession).

After 2006 RH<sub>120</sub>, that you mentioned, another was identified on October 3, 2015 and designated [WT1190F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WT1190F). It impacted Earth on November 13, 2015. It was probably space debris, and not natural.

There's only one other potential candidate that I know of so far: [S509356](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claimed_moons_of_Earth#Temporary_satellites). It was identified on April 8, 2016. It may yet be an artificial satellite, but there are none known that match its orbital period, and it has a color associated with S-type asteroids.

**Update 5/16/2018:**

> S509356 turns out to be 2015-019C, 41929, upper stage from a Long March carrying a BeiDou satellite.

**Update 2/27/2020:**

Now we have an official confirmed mini-moon (temporary natural satellite): [2020 CD<sub>3</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_CD3). It was discovered February 15, 2020, and announced February 25. It is estimated to have been orbiting Earth since around 2017-2018, and it is expected to depart April 2020.

Comment: The 1913 event makes for interesting reading, Chant 1913, O'keefe 1959, and O'keefe 1991 and Lapaz 1956 can all be read online. But it's an inference not an observation, so not really a documented minimoon. As you mention WT1990F is probably artificial (also see [my question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214700/83380)). S509356 is probably artificial according to [this](http://www.satobs.org/seesat/Apr-2016/0083.html) and there is [an ephemeris](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/iau/artsats/artsats.html) for those interested. So it looks like the answer is really "*probably not*".

Comment: I've just asked [Why did they think that S509356 was in orbit around the Earth? Where is the disconnect?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27295/12102)

Comment: I've unaccepted due to [recent news](https://twitter.com/WierzchosKacper/status/1232460436634656769)

Comment: @uhoh Updated. This should be the last update needed as it now definitively answers the question. It does not need to become a list of all future mini-moons.

Comment: I agree 100%, the answer to "Have there been any documented..." is now boolean, but the *SE answer* is a (boolean, url) tuple ;-) I've been on the edge of my seat ever since I heard the conference call with Bill Bottke mentioned in the beginning of the question, so for me this is closure.

Comment: In 2015 there was Orbcomm-2 and then I heard the recording of that phone call and that's what really got me interested in 3-body stuff, so now to see that the predictions were correct and these things *really are visiting us for a while and then leaving on a regular basis* (as cats do) is satisfying. From 2016: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi9w5.png One could always be an anomaly, but now that there has been one since, it's much more likely that they are regular occurrences.

Comment: related news: [...2020 SO may be the Surveyor 2 Centaur rocket body, launched in September 1966. Integrating backwards shows 2020 SO2 to also be orbiting Earth in September 1966.](https://twitter.com/tony873004/status/1307842009709686784)